# How can i change view after an animation?

Tags: ios, animation, ios7

I need your help.
In my app i press a button and an animation starts. After this animation i want to change automatically view without pressing any other button.
How can i do?

Here my code, i think i'm in the correct way, but the animation doesn't start, changes only view and xcode doesn't give me an error message.

```
- (IBAction)button {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.5f animations:^{

        NSArray *playAnimation;
        playAnimation= [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@“image1.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@“image2.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"image3.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"image4.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"image5.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"image6.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"image7.png"],
                        Nil];

    }
        completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    UIStoryboard *Scene1 = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *Sc1 = [Scene1 instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
        [self presentViewController:Sc1 animated:NO completion:nil];

    }];

}
```

Many thanks for your help

Comment: @rene I don' t have an errore message, but the animation doesn't start it changes only view

Answer (score 0):

Most of the animate* methods have sibling-forms that take a completion block. Use the completion to do whatever you'd like.

e.g.

```
+ (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration animations:(void (^)(void))animations;
```

-- versus --

```
+ (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration animations:(void (^)(void))animations completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you started the animation.  Read up on [chaining UIView animations](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2454/uiview-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-use-uiview-animation) for a good overview of the subject.

If you're using UIView animation, set your animation delegate and an `animationDidStopSelector`, e.g.:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"Grow" context:self.btn];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5f];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(doneAnimating:finished:context:)];
// Do stuff you want animated
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

If you're using CABasicAnimation, same thing, just a different interface - set the delegate and `animationDidStop` selector, e.g.:

```
CABasicAnimation* anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale.y"];
anim.delegate = self;
anim.animationDidStop = @selector(doneAnimating:finished:context:)];
anim.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.01];
anim.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:1.0];
anim.duration = 0.5f;
[layer addAnimation:anim forKey:@"grow"];
```

In either case, -doneAnimating will get called when the animation has finished:

```
-(void)doneAnimating:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context
{
    // Do whatever you want next
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do basic UIView animations. These include completion blocks in which you can push/present views.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.5f animations:^{
        // Perform animation here.
        // ex.
        [label setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        // Show new view.
       [self.navigationController pushViewController:[[UIViewController alloc] init] animated:YES];
    }];
```

Comment: Hello Forrest, thank you for your help. This code looks very useful for me, but i tried it and it didn't work. I have an animation with frames and i start it with an IBAction